# How to change landing page to Wordpress site from Magento?

Tags: magento-enterprise, home, wordpress, landing-pages

I have a Wordpress blog and a magento shopping cart. I would like the wordpress blog to show as my home page instead of the magento site. How can I change this? Thank you in advance for any help or advice!

Answer (score 0):

Hope the below link will help you

[Wordpress page as home in magento](http://inchoo.net/dev-talk/wordpress/how-to-use-wordpress-home-page-in-magento-home-page-cms-page/)